# Adminox - Admin Dashboard laravel-backpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I would like to replace the HTML package in question with the one I bought to change the graphic style (Adminox) how can I proceed?

I have offended the path of the template I put the path in the config file

```
view_namespace '=>' vendor.template.admin ',

\ Resources \ views \ vendor \ template \ admin \
```

in here I have to put the bleade files?

where should I put these files?

[folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUEC0.png) 
where the fonts are css and js

[folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFjyM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel Backpack uses [Backstrap](https://github.com/digitallyhappy/backstrap) as a base template.

Use it as an example of how you could modify your Html template into a backpack template, or adapt the existing one to meet your needs.

Best,